# How to achieve ClipToOutLine in below api vesrion 4.4 in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having a view and setted "ClipToOutline" as true to my view. Whenever i run my project in api version 19 its thrown an exception method not found exception but not in api 6 and higher version.

How to achieve "ClipToOutline" in below api 19 version in Xamarin.Android ?

view.ClipToOutline = true;

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this not working is because the java native [`setClipToOutline(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)) method was added in API-21 and hence cannot be used in API-19 due to unavailability.

What you can do though is create a shape drawable and assign it as the background something like below:

**roundedCorner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

And then use it like this `android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"` or this `image.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.roundedCorner);`